# Ubuntu keeps restarting while installing alongside win 8 option

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win 8.1.
I have downloaded the image and written to an usb and I'm trying to install. I selected the **Install Ubuntu** option. I am able to reach the option **Install Ubuntu alongside Win 8** But after I select that it restarts.

Every time it keeps restarting at that point.

Any solution how to proceed further?

I have Dell Inspiron 15R
4GB Ram and 500GB HDD.
No secure boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.. Finally done with the installation.

The ISO file was having problem. I have downloaded from the Ubuntu site only.

The wubi.exe in the installation file was corrupt and was showing as unable to find the correct image in the logs.

Hence the file (wubi.exe) was re-downloaded from the below link

http://ftp.ticklers.org/releases.ubuntu.org/releases//precise/wubi.exe

and then copied to the USB and the installation worked like a charm.